# How do include multiple js files in Rails 6 from a template I found online?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

here's the thing... I lost almost a month on this, and I really don't know what to do. I found a good theme online (in bootstrap) and it has a lot of js files. I decided to build the website in Rails 6 but including js files now is so difficult (for now). If anything, it's very different. I tried adding the files to packs (there are around 10 js files) and require them in application.js. As that was not working (literally nothing happened). After that, I tried adding them to packs and then add

`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'the_js_file', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

for each file. Did rake assets:precompile... Basically, I haven't had a scenario in which I managed to include any of the files. Some links on what to follow (even though I tried following 5,6 articles...), would be great (if you don't have time for full response). I'm afraid that I have to change the code and the js files I found are massive and I really wouldn't want to do that. I'd rather switch to Rails 4.

Comment: You can just use the old setup if you are familar with that.  Add the files to be included `application.js` and then in the layout file put the old `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` .  It still works just fine, it jsut is not there by default anymore

Comment: thank you for your answer. I didn't know this. Where should I put the .js files in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these steps below?

1. create `/src` inside app/javascript folder and pasted all .js files into it.
2. add require `('src/file_name')` to `application.js`.
3. in webpacker.yml, change resolved_paths to `resolved_paths: ['app/javascript/src']`